# Animation stop on hover, begin on mouseout but can't hover again to repeat stop animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Working on a carousel, I have the animation and div wrapping working, but I wanted to add the ability to stop the carousel on hover and restart the animation on mouseout, however it's only working once.  Hover stops the animation, mouseout starts again, but if I hover again it won't stop.

```
var roundabout = setInterval(function(){
        spin()
        }, 3000);
        function spin(){
            var kerosene = document.getElementById('carousel-frame-holder');
            var s = kerosene.offsetLeft;
                if (s >= -1700 ){
                    $("#carousel-frame-holder").animate({left: (s - 600 +'px')});
                    }
                else{
                    $("#carousel-frame-holder").animate({left: (s + 1800 +'px')});
                    }
                //  interruption
                $("#carousel-view-window" ).hover(function() {
                    $("#carousel-frame-holder").stop();
                    clearInterval(roundabout);  
                    });
                $("#carousel-view-window" ).mouseout(function() {
                    setInterval(function(){spin()}, 3000);
                    });
                };



              //wrap
              $('#nav-left').click(function(){
                  var kerosene = document.getElementById('carousel-frame-holder');
                  var s = kerosene.offsetLeft;
                  if (s <= -1 ){
                    $("#carousel-frame-holder").animate({left: (s + 600 +'px')});
                    }
                else {$("#carousel-frame-holder").animate({left: (s - 1800 +'px')});}

              });
              $('#nav-right').click(function(){
                  var kerosene = document.getElementById('carousel-frame-holder');
                  var s = kerosene.offsetLeft;
                  if (s >= -1700 ){
                    $("#carousel-frame-holder").animate({left: (s - 600 +'px')});
                    }
                else {$("#carousel-frame-holder").animate({left: (s + 1800 +'px')});}
              });
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser debug for javascript errors?

Comment: No errors, not sure what else to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the issue is you are subscribing to the event incorrectly. [jQuery hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) handles the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events like so:

```
$('#carousel-view-window').hover(function(){
    //Stop Animation here
    $("#carousel-frame-holder").stop();
    clearInterval(roundabout);
  }, function(){
    //Restart Animation here
    roundabout = setInterval(function(){spin()}, 3000);
});
```

You don't need to subscribe to the `mouseout` event separately.

**UPDATE**

Make sure you store the interval id in the `mouseleave` handler so you can clear it again.

Comment: This is a good method. Though I wouldn't use the hover method as it has been deprecated. I would use: `$('#carousel-view-window).on('mouseenter', function() { //stop }, function() { //start }); the callback will be only called once the mouse leaves.

Comment: Hover isn't listed as deprecated on the jQuery site.

Comment: Truth, you are correct. Hover is fine, but I think the `on(type)` method is preferred. But your example is functional and correct.

Comment: I tried without any luck :$('#carousel-view-window').hover(function(){
   //Stop Animation here
   $("#carousel-frame-holder").stop();
   clearInterval(roundabout);  
   }, function(){
   //Restart Animation here
   setInterval(function(){spin()}, 3000);
   });

Comment: Did you set `roundabout` in the `mouseleave` handler? You have to do that in order to stop the animation more than once. See my update.

Comment: Working! Thanks for the help, us novices really appreciate the help.